# Will this concept for completely autonomous drone charging work

Tags: charging, autonomous

I'm not entirely sure if this goes to drones or electronics. Feel free to move it.

I'm working on a completely autonomous drone system. It is not only supposed to fly autonomous missions, but also to charge itself. For this to work, It must land precisely on a charging platform, so that electrical contact points on it's legs meet with contact points on said platform. However, I'm a programmer and not an engineer, so the electronic parts are always tricky for me. I've made a design, but I'd like somebody to make a sanity check on this and say if it will end in a working solution, a fiery inferno or anything in between...

The following is a design that is supposed to cake care of charging. Upon landing, it disconnects the drone from the battery and powers it via a power source on the ground (the drone carries a companion computer which must keep working). Also, it starts charging the now discoupled battery. Before takeoff, charging is stopped and the battery is reconnected.

The following diagram illustrates this (Red = positive, black = negative, green = signal)

[image]

- Control: Controller for relais1 and -2. May be a microcontroller or a RPI, I haven't decided yet.
- Relais1: Mechanical relais with NC and NO contact.
- Relais2: Mechanical relais with NO contact.
- SSR: High current solid state relais
- Batt: Drone battery (LiPo).
- CHR: Charging electronics, connected to the balance charging port of the battery.
- PWR: Power supply via the charging platform. Voltage can be set to match the battery's cell count.

**Landing**

- The drone lands and connects to the charging platform.
- Control enables Relais2 which closes it's NO contact. The drone is now supplied via battery and charging platform.
- Control enables Relais1

  - Relais1 opens NC contact. The self hold contact of SSR is disabled, SSR opens it's contact, cutting the connection between drone and battery.
  - Relais1 closes NO contact. CHR is now powered and starts charging Batt.

**Takeoff**

- Control disables Relais1

  - Relais1 closes NC contact. SSR gets activated and powers itself via it's self hold contact. The drone is connected to Batt.
  - Relais1 opens NO contact. CHR stops charging Batt.
- Control disables Relais2, which opens it's NO contact, cutting the connection between drone and charging platform. The drone is now powered via battery.
- The drone takes off.
- During flight, the battery is connected to the rest of the drone via SSR, which powers itself with the self hold contact.

Comment: I see the pros and cons of both, but would sitll argue a NC contact for mains power while in flight is a safety concern that trumps having to hold it open when charging/idle

Comment: @Brydon Gibson It totally agree that this is a safety concern. Every forum question regarding power switches I found so far received that answer for good reason. However, my case is different. The power switch no is convenience, so I don't have to rip apart big power cables anymore, it is a bare necissity for my project to work. I use the self hold circuit, so the connection is not based on the Control, but only on the SSR during flight, but I will have to accept the remaining safety concerns.